# How do I make a custom-column sortable in grocery-crud

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

In my controller function, I am adding a custom column called 'PC-MB', which doesnot exist in the database. The value is dynamically calculated using other values in the row. Which works fine.
My question is - how do I make this column sortable. By default, it is not sortable.

```
$this->load->library('grocery_crud');
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$crud->where('is_history',0);
$crud->where('category',"HighwayStats");
$crud->set_table('hwdata');
$crud->order_by('last_update');
$crud->set_subject('Highway Data');
$crud->columns('name',  'last_update', 'PC-MB');
$crud->callback_column('PC-MB',array($this, '_totalpc_callback') );
$gcrud_output = $crud->render();
```

Comment: To answer my own question - sorting on custom columns worked for me by switching the theme to "datatables" $crud->set_theme('datatables'); Dint work with flexigrid

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the new field `PC-MB` does not exists on server side. It is a field that you trying to create at runtime. In `Felxigrid`, it is observed, the order by also set at server side and not on client side. And since the field actually does not exists, it will not have any effect on ordering the same.

There is another option possible for you, you may opt out to go on with datatables themes. There you will have client side sorting.

if you can debug on firebug or some other you will see

> **500 internal server error**

along with some texts in response like this

> ## A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'PC-MB' in 'order clause'
>
> SELECT `hwdata`.*
>   FROM `hwdata`
>   ORDER BY `PC-MB` asc
>    LIMIT 50